# Which encoding is this text /

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding

I have a vb.net program which shows the text as

**Montr\u00e9al**

however this text want to be show as  "**montetreal**" . I tried to encode it in UTF-8.bUT Nowhting changes. Could someone help to identify the encoding or a way to fix it

Thanks in advance Friends

Comment: How are you showing the text? What does your code look like? Where are you getting the text from? This question doesn't have nearly enough information.

Comment: Paste your code in Notepad++ and most of the time it picks up the correct encoding.

Comment: its getting from a weboage. My code is working for almost many places.But some goes up like this. i have a simple regex which scraps a place from website.my code is like, textbox1.text = getrege.value.tosting. Ans once again ,it runs fine with many words,but somewords burst up

Comment: Tried in notepadd++, not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's "JavaScript String Escape", (a function in JS that encodes strings).

If you unescape `Montr\u00E9al` it gives you `Montréal`

And when you escape `Montréal` it gives you `Montr\u00E9al`

Here's an online converter where you can try it yourself [JS Escape Converter](http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html#ad-output)

And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) you can learn more about JavaScript escape() Function.

Comment: Thanks Bro,it works :D Instead of rude comments other than solution, your answer is correct